# Set password to never expire in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

This is my first post, was hoping someone could help me out with this batch script. (I'm super novice with scripting by the by.)

So I was able to write a basic script to add 2 admin users to the computers I configure day in and day out (working with Windows 10). It gets the job done but I can't seem to get the "password never expires" parameter to read correctly and I've tried multiple syntaxes but to no avail.

Here's what I'm working with (again, I'm a novice, be gentle pls):

```
net user /add [user1] [password]
net user /add [user2] [password] 
net localgroup administrators [user1] /add
net localgroup administrators [user2] /add
```

Where in here should I be adding [/MAXPWAGE:UNLIMITED]?
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The `/MAXPWAGE` is an option for the `NET ACCOUNTS` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `WMIC` to set the password expire option for individual users.

```
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE Name='user1' SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

net user /add [user1] [password] /expires:never

Comment: That sets whether the account expires.  It does not set the password expires option.